# Jquery Mobile - Multi Page - getElementById not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I have a number of pages that use the same template. As you know jquery mobile only pulls in the body of the next page when navigating from one page to another.

```
<!-- Page starts here -->
<div data-role="page" class="ui-page">

<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">

<!-- Content Start -->

@RenderBody()

<!-- Content End -->    

</div><!-- contentMain -->

</div> <!-- page1 -->

<!-- Page ends here -->
```

At the start of this template I have a script file referenced:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Apps.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Within this I have a number of functions for to detect the pageshow of each page and register the functions within it.

```
$('#Page1').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {


$('#clear').click(function () {

//Doesn't Work when transitioning between pages - If I refresh or hit this url directly this works      
var word = document.getElementById("word").value;

//Doesn't Work when transitioning between pages - If I refresh or hit this url directly this works 
var word2 = $('#word').val();

});

});
```

My issue is that when I try to get a element via a getElementById or val() after a page transition it always returns as undefined. Although if I refresh the page or hit the url directly it works fine but if I start from another page within my app (even though they all use the same template) and try to navigate to another its seems to scope everything differently and I am unsure how to get elements on a page after the pageshow?

Although this seems to work:

```
alert($("#word").val()); $("#word").val("foobar"); alert($("#word").val());
```

If try something like the below on a button it doesn't hide the button on the page transition but will when I refresh the page directly?

```
$('#Page1').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {

$('#stop').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
```

The Input:

```
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop" data-theme="e" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-hidden">
```

Comment: More than likely you are ending up with duplicate id's due to the way jQM handles pages. To test for that, try `alert($("[id=word]").length)` within the click event.

Comment: no it is returning 1 all the time. I deployed the above below at the start of the script file to try and avoid this this: $('.ui-page').live('pagehide', function () { $(this).remove(); });

Comment: In that case the value really is undefined when you click on it. Are you positive that the input has a value when that click event happens?

Comment: Here's a test: `alert($("#word").val()); $("#word").val("foobar"); alert($("#word").val());`

Comment: Kevin this seems to work for inputs ok which is interesting. But now I'm having trouble finding a button.

Comment: All I can say is keep debugging the selectors to make sure that you are selecting what you expect to select.